Why is there still logging when creating an unlogged table in PolarDB?
I'm trying to create an unlogged table in PolarDB, but it ends up being a logged table. Why is this happening?
Steps to Reproduce:
Start a PolarDB for PostgreSQL 11 instance.
Create an unlogged table.
postgres=# create unlogged table tbl1 (id int);  
WARNING:  change unlogged table to logged table, because unlogged table does not support primary-replica mode  
CREATE TABLE  

There is a warning that forces tbl1 to be converted into a logged table. By checking the metadata of this table, I found:
postgres=# \d+ tbl1  
                                          Table "public.tbl1"  
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description   
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------  
 id     | integer |           |          |         | plain   |             |              |   
Access method: heap

postgres=# select relpersistence from pg_class where relname='tbl1';
 relpersistence 
----------------
 p  -- unlogged table这里应该是u
(1 row)

How can I resolve this issue?
